# VS2015 Visual Studio Insaller=>Setup Project add custom action

Tags: c#, installation, visual-studio-2015

i want to check if master software is installed or not, if master software not install then abort setup. for check that i get code

```
/// <summary>
/// To check software installed or not
/// </summary>
/// <param name="controlPanelDisplayName">Display name of software from control panel</param>
private static bool IsApplictionInstalled(string controlPanelDisplayName)
{
    string displayName;
    RegistryKey key;

    // search in: CurrentUser
    key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
    if (null != key)
    {
        foreach (string keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
            displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
            if (controlPanelDisplayName.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // search in: LocalMachine_32
    key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
    if (null != key)
    {
        foreach (string keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
            displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
            if (controlPanelDisplayName.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    // search in: LocalMachine_64
    key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
    if (null != key)
    {
        foreach (string keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
            displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
            if (controlPanelDisplayName.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    // NOT FOUND
    return false;
}
```

but don't know where to put and where to call this function. please help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

On VS2015, you have to add new project (class library). Add a Class to this project and inherits from `System.Configuration.Install.Installer`.  For example:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Windows.Forms;`

namespace InstallerAction
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class InstallerPathAction : Installer
    {
        //Here override methods that you need for example
        protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
            //Your code and here abort the installation
            throw new InstallException("No master software");
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your installer project, add custom action (Select Installer Project > rigth click > View > Custom Actions > Add Custom Action), Look in Application Folder (double click on Application Folder) Add Output (Select class library that has Installer class) Primary output and click OK.

You can use MessageBox into installer class to debug.

Comment: Tried with Visual Studio 2019 and it worked properly.